# pyspark - error writing dstream to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, pyspark, spark-streaming, dstream

I am having a problem indexing data from spark streaming (pyspark) to elasticserach. the data is of type `dstream`. Below how it looks

```
(u'01B', 0)
(u'1A5', 1)
....
```

Here's the Elastic index I am using: index=clus and type=data

```
GET /clus/_mapping/data
{
   "clus": {
      "mappings": {
         "data": {
            "properties": {
               "content": {
                  "type": "text"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's my code :

```
ES_HOST = {
    "host" : "localhost", 
    "port" : 9200
}

INDEX_NAME = 'clus'
TYPE_NAME = 'data'
ID_FIELD = 'responseID' 

# create ES client
es = Elasticsearch(hosts = [ES_HOST])

# some config before sending to elastic     
if not es.indices.exists(INDEX_NAME):
    request_body = {
        "settings" : {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        }
    }
    res = es.indices.create(index = INDEX_NAME, body = request_body)
es_write_conf = {
        "es.nodes": "localhost",
        "es.port": "9200",
        "es.resource": INDEX_NAME+"/"+TYPE_NAME
    }
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafka")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)

# .....
#loading data to put in elastic : lines4

    lines4.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
        path='-',
        outputFormatClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat",
        keyClass="org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
        valueClass="org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable",
        conf=es_write_conf))




    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Here's the error:

> 17/07/25 15:31:31 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 11.0
>   (TID 23) org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Found
>   unrecoverable error [127.0.0.1:9200] returned Bad Request(400) -
>   failed to parse; Bailing out..    at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.processBulkResponse(RestClient.java:251)
>     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.bulk(RestClient.java:203)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.tryFlush(RestRepository.java:220)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.flush(RestRepository.java:242)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.close(RestRepository.java:267)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.doClose(EsOutputFormat.java:214)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.close(EsOutputFormat.java:196)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$5.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 17/07/25 15:31:31 ERROR
>   Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 21)
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Found
>   unrecoverable error [127.0.0.1:9200] returned Bad Request(400) -
>   failed to parse; Bailing out..    at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.processBulkResponse(RestClient.java:251)
>     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.bulk(RestClient.java:203)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.tryFlush(RestRepository.java:220)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.flush(RestRepository.java:242)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.close(RestRepository.java:267)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.doClose(EsOutputFormat.java:214)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.close(EsOutputFormat.java:196)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$5.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 17/07/25 15:31:31 ERROR
>   Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 22)
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopInvalidRequest: Found
>   unrecoverable error [127.0.0.1:9200] returned Bad Request(400) -
>   failed to parse; Bailing out..    at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.processBulkResponse(RestClient.java:251)
>     at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.bulk(RestClient.java:203)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.tryFlush(RestRepository.java:220)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.flush(RestRepository.java:242)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.close(RestRepository.java:267)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.doClose(EsOutputFormat.java:214)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsOutputFormat$EsRecordWriter.close(EsOutputFormat.java:196)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12$$anonfun$apply$5.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1295)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1119)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$12.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1091)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: can you add the full package import in your script to reproduce the error locally. Also, did you make sure your elasticsearch is accessible from the hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is an error in the way you are creating the index. You need to send the `mapping`in the `body` of the request when creating the index. Here is a working example:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch 

es = Elasticsearch(["http://localhost:9200"])
# create index 
index_name = "clus" 
index_mapping = {
   "clus": {
      "mappings": {
         "data": {
            "properties": {
               "content": {
                  "type": "text"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}


if not es.indices.exists(index_name):
        res = es.indices.create(index=index_name, body=index_mapping)
        print res
```

You should get this `{u'acknowledged': True}` as a repsonse to confirm that you index was created.

Then you loop through your data dstream using foreachRDD and apply a function that would transform the data to json structure `{"content": str((u'1A5', 1))}`and index it as follows

```
doc = {"content": str((u'1A5', 1))}
res = es.index(index="clus", doc_type='data', body=doc)
```

As a side note, it's not recommended to index the data as a list `(u'1A5', 1)` it would be difficult for you to use it in other context such as visualization on kibana.

Comment: When I try your solution, I found that when you capture `es` in a lambda passed to `foreachRDD`, It will throw exceptions: `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects`. How to solve that?